# Authentication using JCIFS

Tags: ntlm, smb, jcifs, cifs, ntlmv2

I'm trying to use JCIFS library to send files to several different Windows Shares in different computers, using a single domain user to make those writing operations. That user as the correct permissions to write on those remote folders.

Unfortunately I'm not having success because I keep getting a RunTimeException mentioning "Plain text passwords are disabled". This kind of makes sense because the password is being passed directly as a variable. Do I have to encrypt it? If so, how can the windows machines recognize the encryption?

Thanks in advance.